# Flutter - LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_items@68190616' has not been initialized.)

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization

I am fairly new to Flutter and am currently trying to use some data from a database to display in a dropdown select menu (using the [mysql1](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1) and [select_form_field packages](https://pub.dev/packages/select_form_field)). The `SelectFormField` needs to be passed a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` as its `items:`-parameter. Whenever I try to run my code I get the exception **LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_items@68190616' has not been initialized.)**.

After looking around it seemed like initializing my item list in `initState()` should do the trick, but I can't get that to work. Below is my **main.dart**.

```
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  ...

  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> _items;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  _getData() async {
    _items = await getData();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column( 
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: SelectFormField(
            controller: nameController,
            hintText: "...",
            items: _items,
            ...
}
```

And this is my **database.dart** file which is able to fetch and format the data in the `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` format I need:

```
getData() async {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];
  dynamic conn = await connect('database');

  var results = await conn.query('select * from data');

  for (var row in results) {
    items.add({'value': row[0], 'label': row[1]});
  }

  await conn.close();

  return items;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try on initState() create Empty map before using it. because when enter build phase it access to null map which throw error.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _items = <Map<String,dynamic>>[] // Empty one
    _items = _getData(); // Or you can assign it immediately 
    super.initState();
  }
```

**Edit**: Try to separate the Initiate from the `initState`, Because the error that you showed me is that must be Future as await
and cast it to the required Type (in this case is `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`)

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  _getDataInit();
  super.initState();
}

void _getDataInit() async {
  _items = await _getData() as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
}
```

Edit2: After investigation, It turns out there wrong Future implementation. I've add `FutureBuilder` and removed `initState` and `_items` variable to solve the issue and here's the working code (just paste it as form.dart):

```
import 'database.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:select_form_field/select_form_field.dart';
import 'package:date_time_picker/date_time_picker.dart';

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var nameController = TextEditingController();
  var dateController = TextEditingController();
  var courseController = TextEditingController();
  var scoreController = TextEditingController();

  final dateFormat = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');

  final database = Database();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    nameController.dispose();
    dateController.dispose();
    courseController.dispose();
    scoreController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool shouldDisplay = false;

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          future: database.getBandits(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return ErrorWidget(Exception(
                    'Error occured when fetching data from database'));
              } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(child: Text('Bandit is empty!'));
              } else {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 30.0),
                      child: SelectFormField(
                        controller: nameController,
                        hintText: "...",
                        items: snapshot.data,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                            return "Hvem er du?";
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Bandit',
                            prefixIcon: Align(
                              widthFactor: 1.0,
                              heightFactor: 1.0,
                              child: Icon(Icons.person),
                            ),
                            suffixIcon: Align(
                              widthFactor: 1.0,
                              heightFactor: 1.0,
                              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 30.0),
                      child: DateTimePicker(
                        controller: dateController,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                              dateController.text =
                                  dateFormat.format(DateTime.now()).toString();
                            });
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        type: DateTimePickerType.date,
                        dateMask: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                        firstDate: DateTime(2020),
                        lastDate: DateTime(2050),
                        dateLabelText: 'Dato',
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Dato',
                            prefixIcon: Align(
                              widthFactor: 1.0,
                              heightFactor: 1.0,
                              child: Icon(Icons.date_range),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 30.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: courseController,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                              courseController.text = "HJGK";
                            });
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Bane',
                            prefixIcon: Align(
                              widthFactor: 1.0,
                              heightFactor: 1.0,
                              child: Icon(Icons.golf_course),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 30.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: scoreController,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return "Indtast score";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Score',
                            prefixIcon: Align(
                                widthFactor: 1.0,
                                heightFactor: 1.0,
                                child: Icon(Icons.sports_score)),
                          ),
                        )),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            _formKey.currentState!.save();
                            shouldDisplay = !shouldDisplay;
                          }
                          shouldDisplay
                              ? showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (context) {
                                    return AlertDialog(
                                      title: const Text("Score registreret"),
                                      content: SingleChildScrollView(
                                        child: ListBody(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      vertical: 10),
                                              child: Text(
                                                  "Spiller: ${nameController.text}"),
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      vertical: 10),
                                              child: Text(
                                                  "Dato: ${dateController.text}"),
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      vertical: 10),
                                              child: Text(
                                                  "Bane: ${courseController.text}"),
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      vertical: 10),
                                              child: Text(
                                                  "Score: ${scoreController.text}"),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      actions: <Widget>[
                                        TextButton(
                                          child: const Text('OK'),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  },
                                )
                              : null;
                        },
                        child: const Text("Submit")),
                  ],
                );
              }
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Creating an empty one make the app possible to run, but gives this error as soon as I click the `SelectFormField`: `_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/popup_menu.dart': Failed assertion: line 877 pos 10: 'items != null && items.isNotEmpty': is not true.)`. Assigning it to _items immediately gives me this error: `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'`, which was an error I was trying to circumvent with this setup.

Comment: @simonbrage I have edited the answer to suit the error message. try it and give me your feedback

Comment: Now if I assign an empty list for starters, `_items` just remains an empty list. If I assign it immediately, I also have to return `_items` in `_getData()`, but in the end I end up with this error again: `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'`

Comment: @simonbrage did you tried after editing and it gives you the same error? it's impossible to be Future<dynamic> because of the `await` keyword.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread it. When I do what you suggest I get the following error in `_getDataInit()`: `_CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast)`

Comment: so the main error here is inside _getData() method because it return null. debug it and see what's going on there and why it returns null instead of List

Comment: Yeah. The odd thing is e.g. if I `print(_items)` in `_getBandits()` it will have the data I'm looking for, but if I `print(_items)` in `initState()` after my `_getBandits();` call, `_items` will evaluate to `null`.

Comment: try to breakpoint the code and follow the code where it gets null. hit me with the result

Comment: Hmm, if I do breakpoint at `_getData()` in `initState()` and step into it, it will show `_items` as `null` all the way through. But if I print it from `_getData()` it will output the correct data.

Comment: on `initState` set `print(_getData().runtimeType);` what the type it gave?

Comment: It gives `Future<dynamic>`

Comment: in my code in the separated method (edited one) put print get data with await with runtime Type. what it yields?

Comment: If I do `print(await _getData().runtimeType` in `_getDataInit` I get this error:  **NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance getter 'runtimetype'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
Tried calling: runtimetype)**. But I get issues with `Future<dynamic>` every time I try to return `_items` from `_getData()`.

Comment: Try wrap the code like this `print((await _getData()).runtimeType)`

Comment: Then it prints `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`. But it is still null when accessing it in my SelectFormField

Comment: I have Idea, why don't you use FutureBuilder in your build tree? isn't more efficient? If you have Google Drive please send the code at it to help you

Comment: @bragi I've Edited the answer try it. it worked for me

Comment: @bragi Please remove the files from Google Drive for security reasons. And change your Simply.com SQL password. And if it solved you problem accept the answer

Comment: OMG. Thanks for that shout, was in a hurry yesterday. Your solution works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: @bragi In service. Don't forget to change SQL password

Comment: Yep, already done. Thanks! :D